# The last unknown symbol in file when file_get_contents is used

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a small problem. When I fetch a page via file_get_contents, the unknown symbol is concantenated to output which destroys the XML structure.

How can I solve the problem?

**code**:

```
    file_get_contents('https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=EMAIL&password=PASSWORD');

    $cookies = array();
    foreach ($http_response_header as $hdr) {
        if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]+)/', $hdr, $matches)) {
            parse_str($matches[1], $tmp);
            $cookies += $tmp;
        }
    }

    //print_r($cookies);

    //echo "//////////////////";

    $cook=$cookies['BREEZESESSION'];
    echo $cook;

    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'GET',
        'header'=>'Cookie: BREEZESESSION='.$cook.'\r\n',
      )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    echo "////////////////////////";
    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    //$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
    $file1 = file_get_contents('https://meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=report-my-meetings', false, $context);

    print_r($file1);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file1);
```

**output**:

```
em2breezgwbhxopvpvknsux7////////////////////////sample1aksamaimeet77842937.adobeconnect.com/sample1/2014-02-28T06:15:00.000-08:002014-02-28T07:15:00.000-08:00true01:00:00.000sample2meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/sample2/2014-02-28T06:15:00.000-08:002014-02-28T07:15:00.000-08:00true01:00:00.000lastTtmeet77842937.adobeconnect.com/lastone/2014-02-28T15:30:00.000-08:002014-02-28T18:00:00.000-08:00false02:30:00.000�
```

Look at the last symbol. It must not exist ideally.

With regards

Comment: please post your code. Is the XML correct if you fetch it via browser?

Comment: @aebersold, yeah it is correct.I will post now.

Comment: Set the correct encoding in the header. This looks like an UTF-8 / ISO encoding problem.

Comment: This is an encoding problem.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez, where to set the encoding??

Comment: @aebersold, where to set the encoding??